# Boot Crashes with 4.8.0-22 Kernel in VMware Fusion

Tags: boot, vmware, 16.10, vmware-fusion

I upgraded my VM (VMware Fusion) to 16.10, when booting I get the following error:

[image]

It does not stop at the same spot every time.

When I boot with 4.4.0-38 there are no problems. I also tried to uninstall VMware tools but that did not help either.

Booting into recovery and then resuming gets me this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was [apparently fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1627198) but has not made it to Ubuntu yet.

```
systemctl disable thermald
```

(from the same link) fixed the issue